How do you write a reduction from a real music piece?

Above is a picture of a real music piece and its reduction from the book I have been reading lately.
I am curious how a reduction is formulated from a real music piece.
I feel like it needs a whole book just for this.
Can someone explain what to consider/not consider when writing a reduction or
recommend any book that does?

The word "reduction" often means something very different, "an arrangement that leaves out notes," as when arranging a symphony into a piano part. This looks like Schenkerian analysis, and yes, it takes a whole book or many of them.

Were you looking for anything more or different in an answer to this question?

"I feel like it needs a whole book just for this": such books exist!

The purpose of a reduction is to highlight some aspect or aspects of a larger work. So the first step is to determine the purpose of the reduction.
In the case of the posted example, it seems the authors are trying to illustrate the intervallic sequence built into the excerpt of Mozart's sonata and how it serves as an expansion of the predominant harmony while then setting up a cadence. In order to do that, they pull out those notes from the score that exemplify that sequence.
One can imagine a process along the following lines:

The authors noticed that the first note of the soprano voice in each measure persists through the measure in a way other notes don't.
The authors then noticed that those first notes form a descending scale.
Perhaps they then noticed that the left-hand in measures 71 and 72 suggests the possibility of a sequence, discovering the down-a-third/up-a-second pattern. (I'm imagining they hadn't already done the harmonic analysis. If that came first, the sequence is even more obvious.)
Having discovered a sequence, the question becomes where it begins and ends. A quick look at measure 70 shows that it, too, contains (an inverted version of) the down-a-third pattern.
Since it's already determined that the right-hand pattern begins at measure 69 and ends at 73, it's easy to discern the main left-hand notes.

A different type of reduction might have focused on showing the harmonic structure, reducing the score by showing chord tones stacked vertically and eliminating non-chord tones. A different reduction might have highlighted the E-D-C-B scale embedded in the third beats of 72 (the E is displaced by an octave).
A fairly detailed, step-by-step example of a reduction can be found in How exactly does Bach modulate from Dmin to Gmin here?.
Some other related questions that may shed further light on the process:

How to make a "reduction" from an arpeggiated bass
In a reduction why are some notes stemmed together?
Is this passage from the development of K 545 another instance of the Circle of Fifths Progression?
Why do I always hear the Zelda theme in Tchaikovsky's Violin Concerto in D Major?


@Sean the key here is: the reduction is not an end in itself, but an illustration of an analysis.
